# How to notify a TableCellEditor that a table row is deleted?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor, abstracttablemodel

I try to implement a TableCellEditor that conains some fields and a delete-button. It works good, but whe the row is deleted, the content in the deleted cell (rendered with TableCellEditor) is **not** updated.

I have tried to call both `fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row)` and `fireTableDataChanged()` in the model when the row is deleted, but it doesn't seem to notify the TableCellEditor. It works when I select another row, and the row index is rendered with a TableCellRenderer again.

Any suggestions on how to notify the TableCellEditor on deletion?

1. *Delete button pressed*

   [image]
2. *Row deleted, but CellEditor content not updated*

   [image]
3. *Row content updated, when a CellRenderer is used again.*

   [image]

Here is the code:

```
public class StringTableDemo extends JFrame {

    public StringTableDemo() {
        
        final StringTableModel model = new StringTableModel();
        model.addRow("Jonas");
        model.addRow("Hello");
        model.addRow("World");
        
        RendererAndEditor rendererAndEditor = new RendererAndEditor(model);
        
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Record.class, rendererAndEditor);
        table.setDefaultEditor(Record.class, rendererAndEditor);
        
        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    class Record {
        String string;
        boolean isDeleted;
    }
    
    class StringTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private final List<Record> data = new ArrayList<Record>();
        
        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
            return data.get(row);
        }
        
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            return Record.class;
        }
        
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return true;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
            if(aValue instanceof Record) {
                Record r = (Record)aValue;
                if(!r.isDeleted) {
                    data.set(row, r);
                    fireTableRowsUpdated(row, column);
                }
            } else throw new IllegalStateException("aValue is not a Record");
        }
        
        public void addRow(String s) {
            Record r = new Record();
            r.string = s;
            r.isDeleted = false;
            data.add(r);
            fireTableRowsInserted(data.size()-1, data.size()-1);
        }
        
        public void removeRow(int row) {
            data.remove(row);
            //fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
            fireTableDataChanged();
            
            System.out.println("row " + row + " deleted");
        }

    }
    
    class CellPanel extends JPanel {
        private final Action removeAction = new AbstractAction("x") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                model.removeRow(index);
                isDeleted = true;
            }
            
        };
        private final JButton removeBtn = new JButton(removeAction);
        private final JTextField field = new JTextField();
        private final StringTableModel model;
        private int index;
        private boolean isDeleted = false;
        public CellPanel(StringTableModel model) {
            super(new BorderLayout());
            this.model = model;
            add(field, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(removeBtn, BorderLayout.EAST);
        }
        
        public Record getRecord() {
            Record r = new Record();
            r.string = field.getText();
            r.isDeleted = isDeleted;
            return r;
        }
        
        public void setRecord(Record r, int index) {
            field.setText(r.string);
            this.index = index;
        }
    }
    
    class RendererAndEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements
     TableCellEditor, TableCellRenderer {

        private final CellPanel renderer;
        private final CellPanel editor;
        
        public RendererAndEditor(StringTableModel model) {
            renderer = new CellPanel(model);
            editor = new CellPanel(model);
        }
        
        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return editor.getRecord();
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, 
                       int row, int column) {
            
            renderer.setRecord((Record)value, row);
            return renderer;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, 
                Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            editor.setRecord((Record)value, row);
            return editor;
        }
        
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new StringTableDemo();
            }
            
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: btw, your editor implementation is (still? havent I seen this before ;-) invalid

Comment: you already accepted the correct answer - so in a way, you did understand my murky comment :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your `CellEditor` doesn't notice that it has to stop editing the cell, when you click on your delete button.

A simple solution would be to add another `ActionListener` to your `CellEditor` and call `stopCellEditing()` every time you click on it. This should work:

```
public RendererAndEditor( StringTableModel model )
{
  renderer = new CellPanel( model );
  editor = new CellPanel( model );

  editor.getRemoveBtn().addActionListener( new ActionListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
    {
      stopCellEditing();
    }
  });
}
```